# C# - How to save a string entered in Form2 in Form1

Tags: c#

I get the default path from the registry for the Steam installation. But if someone has their games installed to a different folder, the user has to enter it in the Configure form. When the form gets closed, that path entered(from the folder browser or by typing the path in manually) should get saved to a string in the main form and should enable a different Combobox which turns on different buttons. I somehow managed to do the save to the mainform string, but  the 2nd combobox doesn't seem to turn on. How can I do it correctly?

** **MAIN FORM ****

```
    public string NewPath { get; set; }

    private ConfigForm otherForm;

    string InstallPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam", "SteamPath", null);

    private void PortalHammerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(InstallPath + @"\SteamApps\common\Portal\bin\hammer.exe");
    }

    private void Gamedropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Gamedropdown.Text == "Portal") // When Portal is selected
        {
            // Enable the Portal SDK buttons
            PortalHammerButton.Visible = true;
            PortalModelViewerButton.Visible = true;
            PortalFacePoserButton.Visible = true;
            // Disable the CS:GO SDK buttons
            csgoFacePoserButton.Visible = false;
            csgoHammerButton.Visible = false;
            csgoModelViewerButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (Gamedropdown.Text == "CS:GO") // When CS:GO is selected
        {
            // Disable Portal SDK buttons
            PortalHammerButton.Visible = false;
            PortalModelViewerButton.Visible = false;
            PortalFacePoserButton.Visible = false;
            // Enable CS:GO SDK buttons
            csgoFacePoserButton.Visible = true;
            csgoHammerButton.Visible = true;
            csgoModelViewerButton.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void ConfigureButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var configdialog = new ConfigForm();
        configdialog.Show();
    }

    private void PortalDifferentHammerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(NewPath + @"\SteamApps\common\Portal\bin\hammer.exe");
    }

    private void NewDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NewDropDown.Text == "Portal") // When Portal is selected
        {
            // Enable the Portal SDK buttons
            PortalDifferentHammerButton.Visible = true;
            PortalDifferentModelViewerButton.Visible = true;
            PortalDifferentFacePoserButton.Visible = true;
            // Disable the CS:GO SDK buttons
            DifferentCSGOFaceposerButton.Visible = false;
            DifferentCSGOHammerButton.Visible = false;
            DifferentCSGOModelViewerButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (NewDropDown.Text == "CS:GO") // When CS:GO is selected
        {
            // Disable the Portal SDK buttons
            PortalDifferentFacePoserButton.Visible = false;
            PortalDifferentHammerButton.Visible = false;
            PortalDifferentModelViewerButton.Visible = false;
            // Enable the CS:GO SDK buttons
            DifferentCSGOModelViewerButton.Visible = true;
            DifferentCSGOHammerButton.Visible = true;
            DifferentCSGOFaceposerButton.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();
        ConfigForm cfgfrm = new ConfigForm();
        cfgfrm.Close();
    }
}
```

}

****CONFIGURE FORM****

```
public partial class ConfigForm : Form
{
    public ConfigForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.NewPath = NewPathBox.Text;
    }

    public void DifferentFolderBrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        string newpath = fbd.SelectedPath;
        NewPathBox.Text = newpath;
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.NewPath = NewPathBox.Text;
    }

    public void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.Gamedropdown.Visible = false;
        frm1.NewDropDown.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: “I have a quite long code” – If you can’t reduce it to the relevant parts, then we can’t help you either.

Comment: Okay. Let's add code and see.

Comment: Adding a whole bunch of irrelivant code is not following poke's instructions.  You should be providing only enough code to replicate the problem, not the entirety of your classes, when most of it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your ConfigForm. Here's your problem:

```
public ConfigForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.NewPath = NewPathBox.Text;
}
```

What you're doing on your Form1 (which I'm guessing is your Main form) is creating a new instance of your ConfigForm and showing it. What you're doing in your ConfigForm is creating a new main form and setting the NewPath = to the value entered on your config form. The problem is this new Form1 is NOT the Form1 that created the ConfigForm. The Form1 that created your config form is not the one getting updated by your code, some arbitrary new Form1 that you create is the one getting updated. This is why your code isn't working as you expected.

Here's the approach I would take. Add a NewPath variable to your ConfigForm just like you have in Form1. Then, add a `FormClosing` method to FormConfig. Do something like this:

```
private void ConfigForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     NewPath = NewPathBox.Text;
}
```

Then, change your code on Form1 to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConfigForm cfgfrm = new ConfigForm();
    cfgfrm.ShowDialog();
    this.NewPath = cfgfrm.NewPath;
}
```

What this code is doing is creating and showing a new ConfigForm on your Form1 when you click button1. Then, when your user closes the FormConfig, the form saves the textbox value to the NewPath variable on the FormConfig. Then, once the form is closed, the code on Form1 resumes. Form1 then looks at the NewPath value that was saved when the user closed the FormConfig. Form1 grabs this new NewPath value and puts it in its own NewPath variable.

**EDIT**

To show/hide comboboxes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConfigForm cfgfrm = new ConfigForm();
    cfgfrm.ShowDialog();
    this.NewPath = cfgfrm.NewPath;
    Gamedropdown.Visible = false; 
    NewDropDown.Visible = true
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't activate the new Combobox.

Comment: I didn't see your code to update the combobox, so I didn't add it in there. After you save the new path with `this.NewPath = cfgfrm.NewPath;`, you will need to do something with it. I wasn't sure where your code was for that. I think it was on your config form, but without an idea of how you want this program to flow, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: The code for updating the Combobox is frm1.Gamedropdown.Visible = false; and frm1.NewDropDown.Visible = true; but it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer to include code for hiding/showing the dropdowns, but that's not going to update comboboxes, that's just going to hide one and show the other.

Comment: But it's the exact same thing I did but it's still not working!

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What are you trying to do and what is it not doing? The code I've supplied will open the config form, get the new path that the user specifies, save that in the NewPath variable on Form1, it will hide the Gamedropdown and it will show the NewDropDown. If you want it to do more than that, you need to add more code. Right now, that's all the code is doing.

Comment: With not working, I mean when I close the Configure form, the new combobox just don't show up. It's still the old one...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are making the secondary form so complicated.  You don't need a pointer to it after you use it and you should be closing instead of hiding.  Try this:

```
class ConfigForm : Form 
{
    public string newPath = null;
    public void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newPath = NewPathBox.Text;
    }
    public void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

...and in your main form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string steamPath = null; // set to starting path
    private void ConfigureButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;
        using (ConfigForm form = new ConfigForm())
        {
            form.newPath = null;
            form.ShowDialog();
            if (form.newPath != null)
            {
                steamPath = form.newPath;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        if (valueChanged)
        {
            // here is where you would handle reloading and changing the ComboBoxes
        }
    }
}
```

This will more cleanly return the new string.  Whatever you want to do as a result of having changed the path can be done after you have disposed of the config form (bringing it up with the "using" conditional automatically does the disposal for you)